# Local Subnet is classified as "Unidentified Network" in Windows. How to give it a name?

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking, subnet

When I several of my computers hooked together with ethernet cables I see this in the network and sharing center:

[image]

It is classified as an "unidentified network" even though all the computers can communicate with each other just fine. Is there some way I can give the network a name, or do local networks always get classified as "unidentified"?

Comment: IIRC only networks with a default gateway can be identified (and thus named). The keyword is _Network Location Awareness_, but I just can’t find the official documentation I’m looking for. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielB, thanks, let me know if you do find it. I'll do some research too.